# Reducing heap size in c# .net and give freed memory to the OS

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I'm aware that with .net 6 we can limit the heap size (as in a previous question here [Limiting the maximum memory used by a C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914893/limiting-the-maximum-memory-used-by-a-c-sharp-program)).

My question: Is it possible to reduce the heap size while the program is running and give the freed memory back to the OS. For example, assume we limit the heap size to 1GB then after running the programming for 10 minutes, we want to reduce it to 512MB. Is this possible?

Comment: The runtime itself manages memory. Any object that isn't used is garbage-collected and its memory freed. Why does your application use 1GB of RAM in the first place? That's almost always an application bug. Perhaps the application creates huge arrays and leaves them in memory. Perhaps it generates a huge number of temporary strings

Comment: Almost certainly not. What would the program do with the other 512MB of heap data?

Comment: As for limiting memory, the best way to do it is by *not* allowing collections or arrays to grow indefinitely.

Comment: For simplicity assume I need to create a huge array of data and that it is not a bug in my program, a 1GB array. Then I decided to reduce it to 512MB, and after I reduce it I want to limit the heap size and return the memory back to the OS. Due to fragmentation in the memory allocate its not guaranteed that the garbage collector will return the memory to the OS.

Comment: You should probably assume that this is not possible.

Comment: TOTALLY mising the point. Many times an application needs a large amount of memory for a short period. This can easily be in the dozens of GB. Then the objects become non-reachable, the GC runs and the space marked as free.... HOWVER the pages are still mapped into the process address space. 

Yes they can be swapped out to a page file, but that does not undo the Virtual Allocation call and the Private bytes remain high.